# How to specify a secret from SecretManager in CloudFormation container definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-secrets-manager

Hey guys I have the following CF configuration and want to resolve a secret from SecretManager.

```
  DefinitionBackend:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    DependsOn: TaskPolicy
    Properties:
      ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt TaskRole.Arn
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      Cpu: 1024
      Memory: 5120
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: admin
          Essential: true
          Image: !Sub XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.${AWS::REGION}.amazonaws.com/some-image:${AWS::StackName}-${ImageTag}
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 8003
          Command:
            - ....
          Secrets:
            - Name: DATABASE_URL
              ValueFrom: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:Dev:SecretString:DATABASE_URL}}'
```

The secret is called `Dev` and there are a few `KEY:VALUE` pairs in it, such as `DATABASE_URL` which is a database connection string.
I want to use the abovementioned configuration to resolve the secret from SecretManager but I am getting an error:

`Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: Create TaskDefinition: The Systems Manager parameter name specified for secret DATABASE_URL is invalid. The parameter name can be up to 2048 characters and include the following letters and symbols: a-zA-Z0-9_.-,`

The database string is in the following format and worked perfectly before in the environment variables:

`"DATABASE_URL":"postgresql://web:PASSWORD@dev.234098234uuoi.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/database"`

Do you have any ideas - am I retrieving it wrong or do I just need to convert it to a different format like Base64 to be able to use it with the secrets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to resolve the value of the secret, and pass that value directly into the task definition. That's not how ECS container secrets work. It's asking you where to get the **value from** not what the actual value is. You need to pass the ARN of the secret, not the value of the secret.

I believe you need to change your template to:

```
ValueFrom: !GetAtt Dev.Arn
```

When the container starts up, the ECS service will look up the value of the secret in Secrets Manager, and add it as an environment variable at that time.

Comment: But how do I specify the key/value pair from that secret's ARN? I can resolve only all secrets at once or do I have to create multiple secrets 1 for each value and store them in the plain text?? Is there any workaround to get secret value from "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:12312434534:secret:Dev-xo2fUj" that is a key/value pair?

Comment: @Daniil in that case the ARN needs to be in the format: `arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:aws_account_id:secret:secret-name:json-key:version-stage:version-id` This is documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html I believe you can just append `:DATABASE_URL` to the end of the string you get from `Dev.Arn`.